# jQuery Mobile .delegate( ) not triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, delegation

I'm quite new to jQuery and I'm struggling a bit on an issue related to delegation.
In my code I have a dynamic page loaded by:

```
    $("#results").delegate('li', 'click', function(evt){
      var queryData = "id=" + $(this).attr("id");
      if ( $(this).attr("id") ){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url:  "wiw_detail_page.html",
          data: queryData,
          beforeSend: onDetailBeforeSend,
          success: onDetailSuccess,
          error: onError
        });
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Please select an Employee from the list");
      }
        return false;
    });
```

This is the onDetailSuccess function:

```
    function onDetailSuccess( data, status ){
      $("body").append( data );
      $("#wiw_detail_page").page( );
      $.mobile.changePage( "#wiw_detail_page", { transition: 'slide' } );
    }
```

Everything works well, as I get my first page moved to "wiw_details_page".
Inside the new page I have a list of fields, under a collapsible, like that:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" id="comData">
    <h2>Communication Data</h2>
    <div id="communicationData">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <a href="#locationMap">
          <input class="goMap" type="text" 
                 name="address" id="address" 
                 disabled="true" 
                 value="<%=employeeprofile-building%>"/>
        </a>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need to attach a click handler on the Address input field, and since this page is not yet created at $(document).ready( ) I attached a delegate to it like this:

```
    // Use delegation, since detail view is not availble at document.ready time:
    $("#wiw_detail_page").delegate('input.goMap','click', function(evt){
      if ( $(this).attr( "id" ) == 'address' ){
        alert("Click!");
        if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
          detectBrowser( );
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( position ){
            newInitialize( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude );
          })
        }else{
          detectBrowser( );
          newInitialize(45.06150, 7.65599);
        }
      }
     });

    });
```

This delegation never takes place and when I click on the input field nothing happens (not even any kind of error).

I have also tried by changing the selector to:

```
    $("#comData").delegate('input.goMap','click', function(evt)
```

And as a desperate try, I changed it to:

```
    $("body").delegate('input.goMap','click', function(evt)
```

Any clue?

Sorry for such a long question and thanks in advance,
R.

Comment: what version of jQuery and jQueryMobile are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.7.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js

Comment: jQM only supports jQuery version 1.6.4, I would suggest downgrading and post back, more here: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/

Comment: Thanks Phill, but doesn't work. In any case, I cannot figure out why the other .delegate( ) method works event in a 1.7.1

Comment: do you have a example link? maybe http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I need to create one with a "local" example, in the live code pages are generated via backend calls.

Comment: Solved: it was the wrong event...working on mobile I should have used pageinit, not document.ready( ). Noobie errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try `#communicationData`, as in:

```
$("#communicationData").delegate('input.goMap','click', function(evt) {...}
```